# How to prevent camera Y axis to invert when inside a vehicle?

Tags: controllers, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Whenever I'm playing San Andreas and I get inside a car, the right analog stick, the one that controls the camera, inverts, so whenever I push it up, the camera goes up, unlike what happens when I'm on foot. 
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using PC or console?

Comment: @Robotnik PC, using saac1.2 with this presets: http://gtaforums.com/topic/198093-ps2-controller-for-pc-version-guide/?p=2919815

Comment: Hi, SAAC has not been updated since 2006. Try to use ginput instead: https://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=24272